# JPA EntityManager caching

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have an entity defined as follows:

```
public class Version {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    @Transient
    private Model model;

    //...
}
```

From what I can see, when a `find` operation is done on Entity Manager, it makes a `SELECT` on the underlying database only once, and then the entity is cached in the Entity Manager. However, I see that if I assign a `Model` to the `model` property, this change is not reflected to the cached entity. E.g. if in one call, a `find` operation is done and `Model` is assigned, when I do `find` again from another EJB, `model` property is `null` again. Is this change not reflected to the cached entity? Perhaps because it's `@Transient`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The entity manager maintains a first level cache, and this first level cache is thrown away as soon as the transaction has ended. Else, the cache would return stale values, since other transactions, in the same application or in another one, could modify or remove the cached entities.

Moreover, concurrent transactions each have their own session-level cache, and thus their own instance of the same entity.

If in a subsequent transaction, you `find` the same entity, a new SQL query will be issued, and a different instance of the entity will be returned.

If something must be remembered across transactions for a given entity, then it should be made persistent in in the database. That's the point of a database.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the new SQL query being issued on second EJB invocation (logging level is set to FINEST). Transaction management is set to default. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is EJB1 calling EJB2, or do you have client call EJB1, and then client call EJB2? Do you understand what transactions are, when they start and when they stop?

Comment: There is only one EJB which is called through Web service. Two consecutive Web service calls are made to the same method. In the first call, I see the `SELECT` queries in the logs. In the second call, there are no queries whatsoever.

Comment: Then either your JPA engine doesn't log all the queries, or you are using a second-level cache. Whatever the case is, my point remains: you have two different transactions, and you are thus guaranteed to get 2 different instance of the entity. Having null for your transient field is expected.

Comment: Could you please post Your configuration (at least server name, version and JPA implementation you are using)?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, it appears I was using L2 cache after all. My provider is EclipseLink (on Glassfish 3.1) which has L2 enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

I have to disagree with @JB Nizet. JPA's EntityManager and Hibernate's Session offer an extended Persistence Context. It is not at all true that "first level cache is thrown away as soon as the transaction has ended".

> Persistence Context can be either Transaction Scoped-- the Persistence
>   Context 'lives' for the length of the transaction, or Extended-- the
>   Persistence Context spans multiple transactions.

https://web.archive.org/web/20131212234524/https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_caching

The solution however is correct, you have to persist changes to the object if you want it to be changed in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EclipseLink then the merge into the shared cache of transients can be configured in two ways.

If a @CloneCopyPolicy is used, then the object from the persistence context will be cloned into the shared cache, preserving the transient fields.

If a @InstantiationCopyPolicy is used, then a new instance will be created for the shared cache, and transients will not be preserved.

If you are using weaving and field access, then the default is @CloneCopyPolicy, otherwise @InstantiationCopyPolicy.  You can also configure this using

You can also control what is merged into the shared cache using a DescriptorEventListener and the postMerge/postClone events.