# When does a query hit JPA 1st level cache and when the query does bypass the cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, first-level-cache

It is clear that, by default, when we execute `entityManager.find(Post.class, 1L);` then the `Post` instance for `id=1` will be retrieved and placed in 1st level cache and then if we again execute the same `entityManager.find(Post.class, 1L);` in the same transaction, the post instance will be returned directly from 1st level cache without querying the database.

My question is the following:

Is the 1st level cache checked only when we try to get the entity by id 
executing `entityManager.find(...);` method ? I mean what if we fetch the same `Post` instance(having `id = 1`) by different property other than ID, e.g. using Criteria query fetching the post by name ? Is it still going to check the 1st level cache ?

What about querying the same row by `native query`, `jpql` or `spring data query method` ? Does JPA/Hibernate parse `native query` and `jpql` queries in order to find out if there is a corresponding entity in 1st level cache ?

Comment: The L1 cache would be checked on any retrieval, clearly, since you can only have 1 object with a particular "id" in the persistence context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA EntityManager caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878422/jpa-entitymanager-caching)

Comment: Better write a small unit-test and turn on sql logging. Then you can easyly check yourself. :-)